# What weathering mechanism leads to reduction of Carbon Dioxide in the atmosphere?

Tags: earth, geophysics, atmospheric-science

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_of_the_Earth) says:

> *The global temperature of the Earth will climb because of the rising luminosity of the Sun, the rate of weathering of silicate minerals will increase. This in turn will decrease the level of carbon dioxide in the atmosphere. Within the next 600 million years from the present, the concentration of $CO_2$ will fall below the critical threshold needed to sustain C3 photosynthesis: about 50 parts per million. At this point, trees and forests in their current forms will no longer be able to survive.*

What is mechanism of this removing of $CO_2$ from the atmosphere?

Answer (score 4):

Carbon Dioxide dissolves in water to form Carbonic acid.
This combines with silicate minerals to form insoluble clays and limestones which are buried by tectonic plates, volcanoes etc

Comment: Does this process increase with temperature?

Comment: The reaction with the minerals probably increases with temperature. Solubility of CO2 in water decreases with temperature